# percentage over total in subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like:

```
Country  is_sale count
AU       1       10
AU       0       30
SE       1       5
SE       0       4
```

I would like to get percentage of the sales (is_sale = 1) over the total per by country level:

Country perc
AU
SE

the input would be:

```
country  ratio
AU       0.23
SE       0.55
```

How do I achieve optimally this with dplyr?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  It is similar to yours, but I was working on that way when you posted the comment

Comment: @docendodiscimus  You can post that as a solution.  It looks really good. I am not posting it as you came up with the idea.  What I meant was that I was doing all permutation/combinations to come up with an answer. I just updated the comment to be concise on comment

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I removed the comment.  It's all yours.  I think it was a mistake from my part.  Usually, I don't update the comments like this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert your binary flag to a boolean, as it makes logical evaluation a little simpler. Then using `dplyr` you can group by `Country`, and calculate your numerator and denominator in two steps of a summarize function.

Take note of the ability to reference `ratio` in the second line of the summarize step; this is one of the things that makes `dplyr` very concise.

```r
library(dplyr)
Country = c('AU','AU','SE','SE')
is_sale = c(1,0,1,0) %>% as.logical
count = c(10,30,5,4)

df = data.frame(Country, is_sale, count)
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(
    ratio = sum(ifelse(is_sale, count, 0)),
    ratio = ratio / sum(count)
  )
```